# Numbered list in Report Builder export to word

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have created a SQL Server Reporting Services Report Builder 3 report that contains a list of several items from a SharePoint list.  I would like the list on the report to be a numbered list, so that when exported to Word, if a user adds another item to the document, the numbering is updated automatically.  I can simulate a numbered list by creating a table and using 'RowNumber' in one of the columns, however this does not get rendered as a true numbered list.  Is there any way to create a true numbered list in Report Builder 3